# Marigolds, clovers, and other plants have leaves mottled with white

Tags: diseases, marigold

I noticed our marigolds all seem to have some sort of leaf-mottling, but since they seem otherwise healthy (perky, blooming), I wasn’t too worried about it. But I’m noticing the same thing has happened to nearby plants: bee balm (wild bergamot), black-eyed susans, purple clover, possibly oxalis (not sure if it’s oxalis or clover in the photo). Nearby milkweed and New Jersey tea plant seem unaffected. It doesn’t look like it’s **on** the leaves like powdery mildew, but like part of the leaf itself. What’s going on? How might I fix it? The affected plants still seem otherwise healthy.

[image: marigold leaves]

[image: clover or oxalis]

[image: bee balm leaves]

Comment: This is some kind of mildew and is common in areas of high humidity. It's mostly aesthetic. I'm not sure of how to treat it.

Comment: Looks very much like damage from tiny insects.

Answer (score 1):

From [My Marigold Leaves Have White Spots](https://gardentabs.com/marigold-leaves-have-white-spots/)

> The red spider mites cause white spots on marigolds. They leave white weaves of webs, feed off your plants, turn the leaves yellow, and slowly kill your marigolds.

Apart from natural methods such as Removing the infected plants and destroying them, there are some methods listed at the same site

> - Rosemary Oil
> - Insecticidal soap
> - Neem Oil

Answer (score 0):

I was told this is from red mites and needs a miticide.